# If a subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is bounded, then it's a subset of some $k$-cell

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{k}$ be bounded. Then there exists a $k$-cell $I$, such that $E \subset I$.

My attempt: There exists $p=(p_1, ... ,p_k) \in E$ and $M>0$ such that $d(p,q)<M$ for each $q \in E$. Choose $a_{i}=p_i - M$ and $b_{i}=p_i + M$ for each $i$, $1 \leq i \leq k$. Since $a_i < b_i$, define $I = \{\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R^k} | a_i \leq x_i \leq b_i, i=1,...,k\}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
 x \in E &\implies d(x,p)<M \\
 &\implies \sum_{i=1}^{k} (x_i - p_i)^2 < M^2\\
 &\implies (x_i - p_i)^2 < M^2 \text{ for each }i\\
 &\implies -M < x_i - p_i < M \text{ for each }i\\
 &\implies a_i < x_i < b_i \text{ for each }i\\
 &\implies x \in I\\
 &\implies E \subset I.
 \end{align*}

Is this valid?

Comment: You might want to define $I$ before using it.

Comment: I defined it as a $k$-cell...

Comment: Whoops. I see the potential issue now. Thanks